# Looping through XML child node

Tags: java, android, xml, nodes

I have successfully looped through an XML list of XML nodes getting name, lastname and salary however when I want to loop through multiple salaries in the costs nodes I get all employee salaries duplicated and not the individual salary posted twice (in the example XML, only 1 employee has 2 salaries.  Salary 2 is never shown).

I cant figure out what is wrong with my loop within a loop (as I copied the first loop which worked perfectly)

```
 <records>
     <employee>
         <name>Sairamkrishna</name>
             <surname>Mammahe</surname>
         <cost>
             <salary>50000</salary>
             <salary>99000</salary>
         </cost>
     </employee>

     <employee>
         <name>Gopal </name>
         <surname>Varma</surname>
         <cost>
             <salary>60000</salary>
         </cost>
     </employee>

     <employee>
         <name>Raja</name>
         <surname>Hr</surname>
         <cost>
             <salary>70000</salary>
         </cost>
     </employee>
     <employee>
         <name>Gopal </name>
         <surname>Varma</surname>
         <cost>
             <salary>60000</salary>
         </cost>
     </employee>
 </records>
```

Java Code

```
 try {
             File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             File yourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "mybits/file.xml");


             DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
             Document doc = dBuilder.parse(yourFile);

             Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
             element.normalize();

             NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
             NodeList nList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("cost");
             for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {

                 Node node = nList.item(i);
                 if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                     Element element2 = (Element) node;

                     tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + "Name : " + getValue("name", element2) + "\n");
                     tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + "Surname : " + getValue("surname", element2) + "\n");

                     for (int j = 0; j < nList1.getLength(); j++) {

                    Node node1 = nList1.item(j);
                    if (node1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element element3 = (Element) node1;

                        tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + "Salary : £" + getValue("salary", element3) + "\n");

                        Salary = Integer.parseInt(getValue("salary", element3));
                    }
                }
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + "-----------------------\n");

                name = getValue("name", element2);
                Surname = getValue("surname", element2);


                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO TestDB VALUES('" + name + "','" + Surname + "'," + Salary + ")");

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node node = nodeList.item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't work as `NodeList nList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("cost");` is getting ALL the cost elements at first and not employee by employee.

I don't exactly know what you can do to fix it in your case, but I think using a library as JAXB can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing it.

```
    NodeList salary = el.getElementsByTagName("salary");
                         for (int j = 0; j < salary.getLength(); j++) {
                             String nSalary = salary.item(j).getTextContent();
                             tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"Salary: "+nSalary+"\n");
                    }
```